# Does my height above the ground affect whether I get frozen by Mei's ult (Blizzard)?

Tags: overwatch

After playing a few games I've noticed, mostly as Pharah, that height can affect whether you get frozen with Mei's ult.

How high do you need to be to avoid being caught in Mei's ult?

Also:

- Do I need to be above her drone that is putting out the freeze?
- Does jumping affect how long it takes for you to freeze?
- Does standing on a nearby object, like a table, barrel, crate, etc.,
  affect the freeze rate?

Comment: In my experience yes, but I'm not sure how far it goes up and down

Comment: While playing Mei myself I dropped an ice wall under myself and still was frozen on top on the ice wall. I'm not sure if I was frozen just before I placed the wall (there is a slight delay  between clicking and the wall forming) or after I was already on top of it.

Comment: well when flying high as pharah, i didnt get frozen, but idk how far up it was.

Comment: When she places her drone and it is spitting out ice it looks like a triangle, but it is like a little tornado. As i was playing with soldier, whos very fast and agile i jumped while in her ult and it felt like it did not affect the time it needs to freeze me. But if i was like two meters above the ult it did not freeze me.

Comment: The AoE of Blizzard is a cylinder, and it has the same effect in the whole area. I have no idea how tall the cylinder is, though. Jumping from ground level will have no effect, however.

Comment: This is just a guess but considering how I saw a Reinhardt get frozen over our Mei's wall, I would guess that the height of the tallest character plus the height of Mei's wall would be the upper limit of her ultimate's cylindrical shape.

Comment: So much science to do tonight... I'll try this out from varying heights both above and below the Blizzard visual circle when I return home :)

Comment: @KizTrap don't forget to science this if you can. I still haven't gotten a change to :(

Comment: @Dragonrage The guy I normally science with was ill on Sunday, and I was doing some Legion raid tests last night. Will get to the science when I can figure out how to test different altitudes with a degree of consistency and precision.

Answer (score 3):

It's right there in the [Wiki](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/mei.html)-ish. The range is 8 meters radius. Meaning you'll ger frozen if you're in direct LOS of 8 meters or less of Snowball. Similarly Reaper has 8-meters ultimate radius as discussed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269524/132203)

Comment: From experience, this answer seems correct. Difficult to test accurate ranges to confirm it's a spherical pattern, but given that other mechanics work in a similar manner, there's no reason this should be different

Answer (score 2):

I've recently learned and tested that Mei's ult is not a circle but actually a sphere. If you are directly above her ult but hovering a few feet off the ground you will freeze. If you were the same height but closed to the edge you are less likely to freeze. The visual for this isn't shown very well.