# Does Reaper shoot above and below him when using Death Blossom?

Tags: overwatch

If Reaper uses Death Blossom, will it damage people who are above or below him? Most of the time I see Reaper's dropping off a roof or wall before using Death Blossom, but could I instead stay on the roof just above the other team and use it and kill them, or use it to kill a Pharah that is hovering above me?

Comment: I saw this title and thought there was a new Last Starfighter game I missed =(

Comment: @StingyJack sorry to disappoint. It's just another blizzard game

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reapers ultimate actually hits everything around him in an **8 meter radius** (360 degrees).

[image: Reapers ultimate description]

Quoting from my link:

> Death Blossom is a very deadly short range damage dealer that does 360 degrees of damage all around Reaper.  Deathblossom is best used when there are a lot of clumped up enemies in a short radius, as it can wipe all of them out easily as long as they do not kill you first while executing Deathblossom.

For more info you can check this: [Reaper strategy guide](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/reaper.html)

People have also been talking in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4lnpdz/death_blossom_hitboxes/)

Quote from Reddit link:

> Currently, Death Blossom's hitbox extends way above what it appears to hit. A reaper is able to ult on the ground and kill a pharah well above him. The hitbox needs to be changed to fit the animation or the animation needs to be adjusted to fit the hitboxes because it's extremely frustrating to play against.

It seems Reaper fires in **all** directions. His animation demonstrates that.

From this [Ability Preview Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2NZsSyRA9s) you can easily see flashes of red diagonally up and down. Demonstrating that he does fire up and down.

Comment: That is just some random guy's blog.  Where does he get his info?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Radius could apply to either a circle or a sphere.

Comment: @blueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I've updated my answer. I tried to include all evidence I could find.

Comment: @Lokuzt Upvoted. I'd be interested in seeing some definitive information on how high it reaches.

Comment: I'm very curious as to whether or not the AOE is a sphere or a cylinder, because if I ult on top of a payload, I want to hit all the targets on all the sides of the payload.

Answer (score 18):

I was playing reaper last night when I panic ult'd; consequentially I have anecdotal evidence to proffer here. I was in the room to the left of that low spot at the very beginning of Watchpoint Gibraltar. I was located at ground level, the enemy Mei located almost at the top of the stair case leading up. Much to my surprise, my ult actually killed her.

[image: Diagram]

So yes, it would appear as though reaper's ult has a considerable vertical hitbox at least above his character. Based on this along with Blizzard's 8-meter radius description, I would assume that it's an 8-meter radius sphere.

Answer (score 2):

You can shoot bellow yourself:

And above: (Can't tell which one's on the payload but they get damaged too at 0M.45s

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but this only shows you can shoot below yourself, not above. I wonder if the AoE is a sphere or a cylinder, in either case.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I've added another clip that shows someone a bit above reaper.

Comment: Die die die rains from above?